# How to create C/C++ proxy for 'ensemble' command

Tags: tcl

I need to have a proxy function (C/C++) called before every command registered in tcl interpreter. For casual commands it is simple, I get `Tcl_CmdInfo`, remember it, and set new `Tcl_CmdInfo` with my proxy function into `objProc` field. When my proxy is called then I do what I need and then I call `objProc` from original `Tcl_CmdInfo`. It works OK.

Problem is that ensemble commands (`info`, `dict` etc.) stop to be 'ensemble' when I call `Tcl_SetCommandInfo` for them. They works fine but cannot be modified by 'namespace ensemble' anymore. Any ideas?

PS. Tracing is not a solution here: it is several times slower and I cannot accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The official API for doing this is tracing. In particular, it *disables bytecode compilation* so command tracking works correctly for bytecode-compiled commands. Yes, it's slower, but that's what you get for being precise with tracking of exactly what is going on. Also, what you are doing will also come unstuck in Tcl 8.6, since that's also got commands with NRE (non-recursive execution engine) implementations, and those don't use the `objProc` field in any useful way. We're looking at even larger modifications for future versions of Tcl (such as native code compilation); your ability to intercept things will be even further reduced there.

In short, you need to use a different approach as what you are trying to do is going strongly against the grain of what works well now. For example, intercepting all procedures or commands created by code you control might be enough, and would have far lower overhead. The easiest way to intercept a procedure is to rewrite the `proc` command:

```
rename proc my_real_proc
my_real_proc proc {name arguments body} {
    set body "[list my_trace_hook $name];$body"
    uplevel 1 [list my_real_proc $name $arguments $body]
}
```

You can then get information about what the procedure is up to in `my_trace_hook` by whatever mechanism you want; it's called from inside the hooked procedure. It doesn't track what all Tcl commands do, but adding that level tracking will always have a significant performance impact (adding it to just the I/O commands is different).

---

Failing that, why are you tracking the ensembles themselves? Just track the subcommands inside them. The Tcl C API can tell you whether a command is an ensemble easily enough, and provides other introspection options as well.

Comment: I didn't consider tracking sub-commands, I will try it, thanks!